# Javascript regex neglect div span tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-group

I have the below text

`<span> is an </span>`

And I wanted to change the **an** into **a** and I use the below regex pattern to do that.

```
const regExFinder = new RegExp("an", 'gi');
const sourceHTML = "<span> is an </span>";
sourceHTML.replace(regExFinder, `$&`);
```

But the output is something like this. Can anybody give me an idea of how to neglect any tag and only change the text inside the tag.

```
<spa> is a </spa>
```

And what if my source HTML looks like this:

```
<div> an <span> is an </span></div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't  manipulate HTML code with regexp. Use the DOM model and operate on the actual `<span>` elements instead.

Comment: Any code sample for how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

```
const str = "<div> an <span> is an </span></div>";
// method 1: negative lookaheads (probably the best for regex)
str.replace(/an(?![^<>]*>)/gi, "a");
// method 2: rely on having a space after the "an" (not reliable)
str.replace(/an /gi, "a ")
// method 3: rely on "an" being its own word (depends on the situation)
str.replace(/\ban/gi, "a")
```

Answer (score 1):

I parse the whole string into a DOM element and then go through all span elements to change their content from "an" to "a", The metacharacter `\b` in the regular expression denotes a word boundary.

**Edit:**

After digging a bit deeper I can **now operate on all text nodes** and change the strings in question:

```js
var html='<div> an <span> is an </span>apple and this <span> is a </span> banana.</div>';

var b=document.createElement('body');
b.innerHTML=html;
//               use the "optional filter function" to do the changes:
getTextNodesIn(b,n=>n.textContent=n.textContent.replace(/\ban\b/g,'a'));

// output:
console.log(b.innerHTML);

// I just realised that I can also use Chris West's original function:
// https://cwestblog.com/2014/03/14/javascript-getting-all-text-nodes/
function getTextNodesIn(elem, opt_fnFilter) {
  var textNodes = [];
  if (elem) {
    for (var nodes = elem.childNodes, i = nodes.length; i--;) {
      var node = nodes[i], nodeType = node.nodeType;
      if (nodeType == 3) {
        if (!opt_fnFilter || opt_fnFilter(node, elem)) {
          textNodes.push(node);
        }
      }
      else if (nodeType == 1 || nodeType == 9 || nodeType == 11) {
        textNodes = textNodes.concat(getTextNodesIn(node, opt_fnFilter));
      }
    }
  }
  return textNodes;
}
```

"Fun fact": In ES6 notation the function can be re-written in an even shorter way as:

```
function getTN(elem, opt_flt) {
  if (elem) return [...elem.childNodes].reduce((tn,node)=>{
    var nty = node.nodeType;
    if (nty==3 && (!opt_flt || opt_flt(node, elem))) tn.push(node);
    else if (nty==1 || nty==9 || nty==11)            tn=tn.concat(getTN(node, opt_flt));
    return tn
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: I think he's looking to replace all "an"s, not just ones in spans.

Comment: Yes, my snippet will only operate on text portions within `<span>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this solution. I've removed all html tag from the string and then applied the replacement operation. It'll work for both of your test cases.

```js
const regExFinder = new RegExp("an", 'gi');
let sourceHTML = "<div> an <span> is an </span></div>";
sourceHTML = sourceHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '').trim();  // removing HTML tags
sourceHTML = sourceHTML.replace(regExFinder, 'a');

console.log(sourceHTML)
```